# is it possible to make a type-generic (template) function in Golang

Tags: go, generics

I'm new to go - just playing with it - but I've written a command line tool - I call about 30 different functions that `return x, err`.  In every case - what I want to do is just panic if there is an error - basically everything works perfectly, or the whole thing fails.

I know there's `template.Must( t Template*, err Error) Template*` - and I know I can make a `check(something interface{}, err Error) interface{}` - but to use it I've gotta do a type cast, which is nasty.

Is it in any way possible to make a sort of generic function `panicIfError` such that I can do something like

```
 x := panicIfError( ioutil.ReadFile( fileName ))
```

and have x come out with the right type?

(I've seen lots of people put the if on the same line - to my mind that sacrifices too much readability - currently my only solution is to make an overload of `panicIfError` for every single type I use, which is not ideal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** Go 1.18 added generics, a generic `Must()` function can be created:

```
func Must[T any](v T, err error) T {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return v
}
```

This is available in [`github.com/icza/gog`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/icza/gog), as [`gog.Must()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/icza/gog#Must) (disclosure: I'm the author).

Original answer follows.

---

The best you can do is declare it to return a value of type `interface{}`, but that's not what you're looking for (you'd need [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to get values of other types out of it).

You want your `panicIfError()` function to return different concrete types. That's not possible in Go.

See related topic in [FAQ: Why does Go not have generic types?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#generics)

Comment: that's actually what I've done at the moment  - seems the least of all evils - return interface{} and just add a type assertion every time I do it.  crazy ugly, but not as ugly as an if compound statement! :)

Comment: As of 2021, is the answer different?

Comment: @PaulStelian Generics is still not yet added to Go (likely coming in 2022), so the answer is still valid.

Comment: Generics are now supported: https://bitfieldconsulting.com/golang/generics