# How to implement c++ template<T> in golang

Tags: c++, templates, go

How to translate this cpp code to golang ?

```
template<T> class CppTemp {
    T  a;
    T* pa;
    T foo(T &t);
};

template<T> T foo2(const T &t)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go doesn't support templates or generics. There are three things you can do:

- use non-empty interfaces where applicable
- generate code with `go generate`
- use `interface{}`:

  ```
  type GoTemp struct {
      a interface{}
  }

  func (gt *GoTemp) foo(v interface{}) {
      // ...
  }

  func foo2(v interface{}) {
      // ...
  }
  ```

Comment: thank you very much , according to my code , which way do you prefer most

Comment: and what is  non-empty interfaces

Comment: Non-empty interfaces are interfaces with methods. See e.g. [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader). I can't tell you which is the best way because there is no good way. I'd say, start with `interface{}` and go from there.

Comment: Generics are now supported: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38690544/is-it-possible-to-make-a-type-generic-template-function-in-golang/38691996, see edited answer.